# R code of scatter plot for four variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried plotting ASB vs YOI for each Child grouped by Race

I got something like:

```
library(tidyverse)
Antisocial <- structure(list(Child = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L,  4L), ASB = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L), Race = c(1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Y92 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,  1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Y94 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,  0L, 1L, 0L), YOI = c(90L, 92L, 94L, 90L, 92L, 94L, 90L, 92L,  94L, 90L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(data = Antisocial, aes(x = YOI, y = ASB)) + 
  geom_point( colour = "Black", size = 2) + 
  geom_line(data = Antisocial, aes(x= Child), size = 1) +
  facet_grid(.~ Race)
```

Plot Image I generated: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sZVsRFiGC0dIGg0GWhHhNDCaiW2iB-ky/view?usp=sharing

Full dataset- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UeVTJ1M_eKQDNtvyUHRB77VDpSF1ASli/view?usp=sharing

I want to use 2 charts side by side Race=0, Race= 1 to plot ASB vs YOI for each Child grouped by Race. The line, however, should only connect to dots of the same child. As it is right now, all the dots are connected. Furthermore the scale of YOI should be (90,94).

Can you suggest what change should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Give us an example code with `dput(Antisocial[20, ])`, for the first 20 rows or so.

Comment: Here you go:                                                    
`structure(list(Child = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L), ASB = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L), Race = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Y92 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Y94 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), YOI = c(90L, 92L, 94L, 90L, 92L, 94L, 90L, 92L, 
94L, 90L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for providing the data. I changed 4 observations to race 0 to have some variation:

```
library(tidyverse)
Antisocial <- structure(list(Child = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L,  4L), ASB = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L), Race = c(1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Y92 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,  1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Y94 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,  0L, 1L, 0L), YOI = c(90L, 92L, 94L, 90L, 92L, 94L, 90L, 92L,  94L, 90L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
        
ggplot(data = Antisocial, aes(x = YOI, y = ASB, , group = Child)) + 
    geom_point( colour = "Black", size = 2) + 
    geom_line()+
    facet_grid(.~ Race)
```

To connect the dots for each child, you need to include `group = Child` in the code. I think this is what you want? Let me know if this solved your problem :)

Comment: Thanks! I improvised what you did and I am able to get lines for Child but I cannot add legends. Also in the generated graph, the lines are not very Significant and It seems to be very difficult to understand the graph. Do you think adding boxplot or any other will make it clear? If yes please edit the code. `Anti <- Antisocial[0:60,]
  ggplot(data = Anti, aes(x = YOI, y = ASB, group= Child)) + geom_point( colour = "Black", size = 2) + geom_line(color= Anti$Child) + facet_grid(.~ Race) `

Comment: To get a legend: `ggplot(data = Anti, aes(x = YOI, y = ASB, group= Child, color = "Child)) +....`. And I think a boxplot for each race would make the interpretation more clear.

Comment: If this awnsers the questin let me know! And maybe accept the awnser so others see it too, but obviously you dont have to :)